# List is empty after assignment from another list

Tags: java, arraylist

I am trying to process list of my Class A.

Method:

```
public List<A> get(String var) {    
List  <A> list= new ArrayList <A>();
A obj = new A();
Session session = this.getHibernateTemplate().getSessionFactory().openSession();
Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(A.class);
criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("name", var)); 
Iterator<A> it = (Iterator<A>) criteria.list().iterator();
while(it.hasNext())
{
obj = it.next();
list.add(obj);
}
return list;
}
```

Method Call:

```
List  <A> list2= new ArrayList <A>();
list2 = get (var);
```

On debug I can see list values. Problem is list2 is empty. Why is this happening?

Comment: Please include a *complete*, *runnable* example that shows the problem. Right now the question is unanswerable.

Comment: You've skipped the most important part of your question. Please show us the logic you use to populate the list in your `get` method. Also, did you ensure that `list` is populated when it is returned by `get`?

Comment: Did you debug/ensure, that the returned list is not null/empty?

Comment: @David returned list is not empty

Answer (score 0, accepted):

list2 is empty because

```
   public List<A> get(String var)
```

returns empty list.

The first line

```
    List  <A> list2= new ArrayList <A>();
    list2 = get (var);
```

is overridden with the result from get().

**UPD**

You call criteria.list() twice!

Remove this:

```
Iterator<A> it = (Iterator<A>) criteria.list().iterator();
while(it.hasNext())
{
obj = it.next();
list.add(obj);
}
```

You should get ConcurrentModificationException actually, but anyway this is wrong.

**UPD2**

Try this:

```
public List<A> get(String var) {
    Session session = this.getHibernateTemplate().getSessionFactory()
            .openSession();
    Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(A.class);
    criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("name", var));
    return criteria.list();
}


List<A> list2 = get (var);
```

Comment: I can see return list with data on debug

Comment: You still need to remove that iteration part. list = criteria.list()  is enough. And do not initialize list in both places you did.